# How change relation between parents and childs in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, parent, children, relation

How change relation  between parents and childs in elasticsearch?
I could not find information about it.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27867097/4425523) i gave the example of a simple mapping.
How i can change street of address? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
You should change "_parent" field, and call "flush" or "refresh" methods of ES, so that new data has been ready for search.